# swapping elements in matrices a and b above main diagonal when elements are equal and if number of rows columns of matrix a == rows columns matrix b

Tags: java

the code is supposed to change the elements of matrix a and matrix b above the main diagonal only when the number of their elements is equal and when the number of rows and columns of a == number of rows and columns of b for example A MxN == B MxN , A NxM == B NxM, any help will be much appreciated.

```
    Matrix matrixA = new Matrix("Matrix A", 4, 4);
    Matrix matrixB = new Matrix("Matrix B", 4, 4);

    matrixA.RandomElements(-10, 10);
    matrixB.RandomElements(-10, 10);

    System.out.println(matrixA.toString());
    System.out.println(matrixB.toString());

    matrixA.swapElements(matrixB);
    matrixA.printArray(matrixA);





public Matrix(String name, int numberofRows, int numberofCols) {
    this.name = name;
    elements = new int[numberofRows][numberofCols];
}

void RandomElements(int a, int b) {
    Random number = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < elements[i].length; j++) {
            elements[i][j] = number.nextInt(b + 1) + a;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String text = "";
    text += name + "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < elements[i].length; j++) {
            text += String.format("%6d", elements[i][j]);
        }
        text += "\n";
    }
    return text;
}

public void swapElements(Matrix matrix){
    if (elements.length == elements[0].length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j < elements[i].length; j++) {
                if (i > j) {
                    int temp = elements[i][j];
                    elements[i][j] = elements[j][i];
                    elements[j][i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("not valid");
    }
}


public void printArray(Matrix matrix){
    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        for ( j = 0; j < elements[0].length; ++j)
            System.out.print(elements[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

input is

Matrix A

```
 -8    -5    -5    -9
 -1    -2    -2    -3
 -10   -10     0    -3
 -4   -10    -6    -6
```

Matrix B

```
-8    -7    -2    -2
-6     0    -7     0
-1    -2    -2    -2
 0    -6    -6    -7
```

desired output is

Matrix A

```
-8    -5    -2    -2
-1    -2    -7     0
-10   -10     0    -3
-4   -10    -6    -6
```

Matrix B

```
-8    -7    -5    -9
-6     0    -2    -3
-1    -2    -2    -2
 0    -6    -6    -7
```

Comment: Your requirements described in the question and the code provided in the method `swapElements` does not match.You ignore the parameter and only check if your matrix has the same number of rows and columns. And you don't swap the elements of the calling object with the elements of the passed object but the elements below and above the digonals in the same object.

Comment: @Eritrean I am kinda new to coding(3 months of experience tbh) what do u suggest changing in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below should be what you are looking for assuming all other methods except the `swapElements` do what they are sposed to do.

```
//changed param name to make it clear
public void swapElements(Matrix other){
    //if this object have the same dimenssions as other object
    if (this.elements.length == other.elements.length && 
        this.elements[0].length == other.elements[0].length) {

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j < elements[i].length; j++) {
                if (i < j) {
                    int temp = elements[i][j];
                    this.elements[i][j] = other.elements[i][j];
                    other.elements[i][j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("not valid");
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Move the println statment into the for loop. **Tipp** Even though single statement if and for loops do not need curly braces using them is considered best practise.

```
public void printArray(Matrix matrix){
    System.out.println(matrix);  
}
```

Comment: it seems like my print method is wrong too, can u suggest any change to be made in my print method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: the printArray shows the matrix that was made before the swapelements method, should i store the swap elements into a new variable and then call the printarraymethod?

Comment: i added the main method up above

Comment: thank you so much, one last thing, how can i print the matrices after the swap elements method just like i did before the swap elements method?

Comment: @paradoxum If this has solved your problem please accept my answer by ticking the check mark on the left side of the answer below the arrows

Comment: 4   Matrix A
   -10     0    -3    -7
    -4    -2    -6    -5
    -2    -2    -2   -10
   -10    -4     0    -6    the output is like this(it shows one more number next to the name of the array)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can not reproduce.

Comment: nvm i fixed it, thx a lot man u really helped me